# RegEx for single asterisk (*) and alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a javascript regex that accepts any alphanumeric character (can be any amount of characters or 0 characters if an asterisk is present) and a single asterisk anywhere in the string (but it does not need the asterisk).

**Matches**

```
*
abc
*abc
abc*
a*bc
```

**Invalid Matches**

```
**
*_abc
*abc*
abc**
**abc
```

I have

```
^([A-Za-z\d*]?)+$
```

but that matches multiple asterisks and I'm not sure how to only allow one https://regex101.com/r/a1C9bf/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!(?:.*\*){2})[A-Za-z\d*]+$/gm
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a1C9bf/2)

Negative lookahead `(?!(?:.*\*){2})` fails the match if there are more than one `*` in input.

Comment: Yup, this is the one, thanks! I'll mark it as the answer in a couple minutes :)

Comment: can you please solve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023527/mod-rewrite-query-parameter-validation-and-blocking-also-request-url-blocking)

Answer (score 1):

Without requiring any look-ahead, you could use `^([\da-zA-Z]+|[\da-zA-Z]*\*[\da-zA-Z]*)$`
https://regex101.com/r/xW2IvR/2

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
^(?=.)[A-Za-z\d]*\*?[A-Za-z\d]*$
```

This will match any string that that's at least one character long (`(?=.)`), starts with zero or more alphanumeric characters, contains an optional `*`, and ends with zero or more alphanumeric characters.

You could also replace `[A-Za-z\d]` with `[^\W_]` to make it a little shorter (but slightly harder to read):

```
^(?=.)[^\W_]*\*?[^\W_]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

You want one match one of two possible cases:

1. an asterisk surrounded by zero or more alphanumeric characters
2. one or more alphanumeric characters

Then this is your regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z\d]*\*[a-zA-Z\d]*|[a-zA-Z\d]+)$
```