# Mod rewrite query parameter validation and blocking also request url blocking

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

On my site, only few query query parameters are allowed but, some scanners or hackers trying to access url with unique parameters which my php application doesn't support, I can block them in php application level, by validating `$_GET` parameters, but my server is getting loaded, so I want to show 403 if parameters are not valid

**Query parameters can be in any order**

So far what I tried is as follows

```
# IF there is query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$

# Then parameters can be only query|debug|lang
# block any extra parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|$)(query|debug|lang)=[^&]+(&|$) [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

But problem here is

```
http://example.com/search?query=test&debug=on&lang=en&foo=bar
```

its passing even if hacker pass `foo=bar`, I want to show 404, strict parameter checking before reaching php application.

Here is : [Rewrite Tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=2316ac3b-d984-5ec9-84f9-8b88553e71f0)

It's not showing 404

Example of Valid url with query parameter

`http://example.com/search?query=test&debug=on&lang=en`

Example of INVALID url with query parameter

(Check Is there any query parameter other than allowed one ??? )

```
http://example.com/search?query=test&debug=on&lang=en&foo=bar
http://example.com/search?a=1
http://example.com/search?a=2
http://example.com/search?query=test&a=1
```

Same I can do in php, But I want to block request before reaching my php application.

```
$allowed = array('query', 'lang', 'debug');
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
         if(!in_array($key, $allowed))
         {
                  http_response_code(403)  
                  die('Forbidden');
         }
}
```

Also on my website, request uri allowed chars are `[A-Za-z0-9_-]`

How can I block if request uri containing anything extra

Also want to know,

1. is it possible in rewrite to check POST variables too ?
2. I see many suspicious agents string how can I block them
3. Also I see in referral url hackers trying to inject xss and sqlinjection string how can I block them.

Comment: Can you post some  url examples  that you want to deny/allow access to ?

Comment: @starkeen : example `http://example.com/search?query=test&debug=on&lang=en&foo=bar` is invalid because only `lang,debug,query` are allowed query parameter, if any scanner tries other than these three parameter, should get 403

Comment: @starkeen : added more description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace your existing rule with this rule:

```
# Then parameters can be only query|debug|lang
# block any extra parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?!(?:query|debug|lang)=[^&]+(?:&(?:query|debug|lang)=[^&]+)*$). [NC]

RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This rule will return `403` if any query parameter other than `query|debug|lang` is present in URL.

Here `(?!...)` is a [negative lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that will fail if query string has anything except given parameters.

---

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?!`: Start of negative lookahead

  - `(?:query|debug|lang)=[^&]+`: Match one of the 3 allowed query parameter and it's value
  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group

    - `&`: Match a `&`
    - `(?:query|debug|lang)=[^&]+`: Match one of the 3 allowed query parameter and it's value
  - `)*`: End non-capture group. `*` means 0 or of this group
  - `$`: End
- `)`: End of negative lookahead expression
- `.`: Make sure query string is not empty

In simple words negative lookahead asserts failure when query string has any query parameter other than the 3 allowed parameters.

Comment: Oh, You saved me, Will you please explain This regex `^(?!(?:query|debug|lang)=[^&]+(?:&(?:query|debug|lang)=[^&]+)*$).`, Looks like now I can block some scanners hitting, Also I want to enable only request uri can have only `[A-Za-z0-9_-/]` but its blocking some encoded chars, I am not sure, how to filter out only safe chars in request uri

Comment: thank you so much, if you have time please guide me towards web safe chars for request uri, currently all my urls using only `[A-Za-z0-9_-/]+` chars but to how to deal with encoded chars with `%` ?

Comment: Keep hyphen at last char in character class to make it `[\w/-]+`.  Other than these characters all other special characters need not be there

Comment: sir can you please guide me on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56679932/apache-proxy-rewrite-setup-for-specific-file-types-inside-sub-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

#if there is query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
# Then parameters can be only query|debug|lang
# block any extra parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(query|debug|lang)=[^&]+&(query|debug|lang)=[^&]+&(query|debug|lang)=[^&]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

This will return a 403 forbidden error for URLs not  matching the RewriteCond regex.

Comment: `query=.+&debug=.+&lang` order is not fixed, it can be anywhere, example `http://example.com/search?debug=on&query=test&lang=en`

Comment: @user3637224 I have updated the pattern . Does it work now?

Comment: @user3637224 Thats what you mentioned in your Post. You said that the valid url is `http://example.com/search?query=test&debug=on&lang=en` .  The rule should work fine for that URL. What do you mean by `/search?debug=on` ? Is this also the part of your valid urls?

Comment: Actually parameters can be in any order, and allowed are 3 parameters, which can be either `query` or `lang` or `debug` or all three

Comment: @user3637224 ok , in that case you can use a rewriteCond to check querystring with a single key value pair. Add the following condition right above the rule or below the second RewriteCond `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(query|debug|lang)=[^&]+$ [NC]` .

Comment: @user3637224 You must not replace, but *add* the `RewriteCond` to the existing `RewriteRule`.