# Apache proxy / rewrite setup for specific file types inside sub directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

Recently I had to migrate somesite which was nearly 15 years old, consider the new url is

https://mynew.domain.com

and the old site was https://myold.domain.com (Internal IP : 192.168.1.15, which is not available in public domain)

In old site it was having directory called "sitefiles", in which many sub folders and files like images, files etc

So what I want to achieve is suppose if user hits url on browser which was  file request with white listed extensions such (.jpg , .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .gif, .svg) say for example, then serve those requests from internal IP

https://mynew.domain.com/sitefiles/events/somedirectory/somefile.jpg

https://mynew.domain.com/sitefiles/somedoc.jpg

Please note sitefiles directory is quite big, and its nested, I don't know how to go about this, currently what I tried is

```
ProxyPass /sitefiles/ http://192.168.1.15/sitefiles
ProxyPassReverse /sitefiles/ http://192.168.1.15/sitefiles
```

But

- how do I whitelist is really the request is for whitelisted files ?
- absolute path to file is really not predictable for me, can we pass something like

`ProxyPass %{REQUEST_URI} http://192.168.1.15/$1`

I also tried, below one which gives me Bad Request your browser sent a request that this server could not understand

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitefiles
RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://192.168.1.15/$1 [P,L]
```

Above same one if I modify  `[P,L]` to `[R=301,L]` it properly redirecting to other server, not sure why proxy is not working

Comment: Why is whitelisting important? If browser request comes for an unknown extension such as `.txt` then it will just result in 404 after `ProxyPass` forward.

Comment: @anubhava : Sir there any many files, i would like to allow only few extensions such as pdf jpeg jpg png svg doc docx ppt pptx

Comment: @anubhava : Sir I tried some more rewrite attempts, please see update, but didn't succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow certain whitelisted extensions you may use mod_rewrite rule instead of `ProxyPass`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sitefiles/.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|pdf|docx?|gif|svg|pptx?)$ http://192.168.1.15/$0 [L,NC,P]
```

`P` flag in this rule does what `ProxyPass` does for you.

This assumes `mod_proxy` is properly setup in Apache config.

Comment: I am getting 400 bad request, what could be the issue ?

Comment: What happens when you use flags as `[L,NC]` ?

Comment: without `P`, if I use, browser is downloading file, but with `P` its 400

Comment: That means `mod_proxy` is not setup properly. You will have to contact your site support.

Comment: thank you, here is result of `apachectl -M | grep proxy` `proxy_module (shared)
Syntax OK
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
`

Comment: Make sure your new web server is able to reach `http://192.168.1.15/` which is not reachable from internet.

Comment: I tested on one more machine your code working perfectly, which had `proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
` thanks a ton, you saved me